# Monitor Never Shuts Off After Upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, screen

After upgrading to 20.04 from 19.x (can't recall which), my monitor now will never shut off even though it did so without fail prior to upgrade. Automatic suspend is off (as with a previous monitor I would stay at garbled noise on wake up), but blank screen is set to 15 minutes.

Of note: I'm using a custom monitor profile that I set to achieve a 2560x1440 resolution output. I had that prior to the upgrade as well, but not during the previous upgrade cycle (was not using this monitor/profile when upgrading from 18.x to 19.x).

I'm not really interested in a command mapped to a keystroke as I frequently just walk away from the machine not knowing if I'll be back in 30 seconds or 4 hours. I am willing to install additional software to handle this if it can't be handled by...Unity? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem immediately! I usually use my power button to turn off the display, but even after setting the timer to 1 minute, the display just never turned off!

Google will tell you that there's a keyboard/mouse that's waking the display. I disabled  EVERYTHING, but display would still wake up.

I rolled back my win10 version to 1909, and my display is turning off again. I then reinstalled 2004, and now things aren't working again.

Looks like a bug with a the build.